# UITableView header view resizeing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

i have put a UISearchBar into uitableview headerview and in viewcontroller viewdidLoad methods sets the headerview height to 0 and hide the searchbar, and wanted to show searchbar when the button will touched, in touch handler i restore the headerview height and show uisearchbar, but the searchbar overlays the first row of tableview. is there any way to avoid overlaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the clipsToBounds property of the headerview to YES will do just that.

Comment: nothing was happened, where i must set this property ? i set it before restoring the original size

Comment: It should already be set when the height is 0; that's when the searchbar will overlap the tableview below because it doesn't fit. Typically you'd set it right after creation of the headerview, but setting it just before making its height 0 works too.

Comment: no it doesn't work, maybe i do something wrong? here is my code. in viewDidLoad method 
CGRect headerframe=self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    [self.searchBar setHidden:YES];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame=CGRectMake(headerframe.origin.x, headerframe.origin.y, headerframe.size.width, 0);

and in touch handler

[self.searchBar setHidden:NO];
    CGRect  headerframe=self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame=CGRectMake(headerframe.origin.x, headerframe.origin.y, headerframe.size.width, 44);

Comment: The changes you make to the headerview won't be visible until you call setTableHeaderView on the tableView. You should copy self.tableView.tableHeaderView to a variable, adjust the settings like you do now and then call setTableHeaderView.

Comment: thanks Stuart it works, and one more question should i create a copy or retain header view object before setting it or cocoa-touch take care of retaining the object before setting it ?

Comment: Glad to help. The UITableView will automatically retain the header view for you.

Answer (score 2):

change clipsToBounds to YES in the headerView.